# How to handle errors in caller sub

Tags: vba, ms-access, error-handling

I'm trying to capture an error in my Access application but it always shows the system message box and debug window.

I have added a "On Error" statement and check for a possible number, but otherwise I want this error to raise and be handled in a previous sub to show a msgbox and have the whole current process aborted.

The chain of steps is:

- The user clicks a "new" button. It's click event contains a DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec. This method contains a "On Error" statement with a MsgBox.
- The Form_Current event is triggered. At some point it calls a sub MySub
- Inside MySub I have a "On Error" statement, where its handling block checks a concrete error code.
- As an else case I want to raise a new error code and description, or the same, but instead of catching the error in the first step (the click event handler) and show the MsgBox to the user the execution interrupts and shows the error in a debug dialog (with the vba editor open).

What should I do to "release" the error handling in order to allow it to reach the previous calls?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I'll try to add a code sample.

Click event:

```
    Public Sub MyBtn_Click()
    On Error GoTo handler
        DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
        Exit Sub
    handler:
        MsgBox "Handled!"
    End Sub
```

Form current event:

```
    Private Sub Form_Current()
        MySub 'Call to MySub method
    End Sub
```

MySub method:

```
    Public Sub MySub()
    On Error GoTo handler
        err.raise 1000, , "Custom error raised to test my handlers"
        'Current code here, with DB methods that my fail and I wanted to get under control
        ' ... DoCmd.RunSQL and that stuff
        Exit Sub
    handler:
        'if err.Number = xxx then ...
        'Not in an if block here, but will be in an else case
        Dim errNum as Long
        Dim errDesc as String
        errNum = err.Number
        errDesc = err.Description
        err.Clear
        'VB stops here and gives an error. Forces debugging in this line.
        err.Raise errNum, , errDesc
    End Sub
```

So, I want to raise a custom error from MySub to be handled in MyBtn_Click.

Comment: You don't show the error message here so it is not clear what type of error you receive. Any way if you would like to catch such errors at a higher level (application level errors) use the Form On Error event and put inside code to check the error data and take action you need. You can cancel the system message as well by using `Response = acDataErrContinue` inside the **Form_Error** event subroutine.

Comment: A [mcve] would help a lot to understand your problem.

Comment: Have you checked your error trapping settings in VBA? (Tools -> Options -> General -> Error Trapping)

Comment: From your description it seems that all your code is placed in forms or regular modules, so you can set the trapping settings to "Break on Unhandled Errors" and try again.

Comment: Ok, I've added some code to reproduce. The error trapping settings have the "Break on unhandled errors" checked. About the Form_Error, it applies to Access errors, not vb runtime errors. [See here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.error)